# Unable to make a error plot [Value error:too many values to unpack (expect 1)]

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, error-handling, valueerror

Code :

```
    E,=plt.plot(bl,semullts_mean,color='b',marker='o',label='Sequential')
    F,=plt.plot(bl,semulltr_mean,color='c',marker='o',label='Random')
    legend3 = plt.legend(handles=[E,F]) #(CORRECT)
```

```
     K,=pylab.errorbar(bl,semullts_mean,yerr=semulltr_std,ecolor='m',color='g',marker='o',label='Sequential')
```

```
  L,=pylab.errorbar(x=bl,y=semulltr_mean,yerr=semulltr_std,ecolor='y',color='g',marker='o',label='Random') #(ERROR)
```

Here is the error log shown in my code

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-21aefb184d1d> in <module>()
    190 #semulbwr_std=np.reshape(semulbwr_std, (semulbwr_std.shape[0], ))
    191 
--> 192


    K,=pylab.errorbar(bl,semullts_mean,yerr=semulltr_std,ecolor='m',color='g',marker='o',label='Sequential')
        193 
    L,=pylab.errorbar(x=bl,y=semulltr_mean,yerr=semulltr_std,ecolor='y',color='g',marker='o',label='Random')
        194 legend5 = pylab.legend(handles=[K,L])

    #(ERROR LOGS)

    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

So here it is. I don't know why I can't create errorbar with variables that is available to create a plot
The first two line is correct and it is able to generate plot. But when I use the same variable to generate errorbar. It constantly post this error. And I didn't find a good way to solve it

I'm using matplotlib. The bl, semulltr_mean and semulltr_std etc are lists with 11 element. For example, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]. They are all with same amounts of elements. I don't know what cause this problem

Comment: I have used numpy to convert it into numpy.array. But it seems not working

Comment: BTW, use of the pylab module is [not recommended](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related), you should use `matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar()` instead

Comment: What is the difference between these two modules?

Comment: It's explained in the link provided. pylab was supposed to help people transitioning from MATLAB, but I guess the maintainers feel it's no longer necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the coma after `K` and `l`

```
K,=pylab.errorbar(...
 ^
 |
```

should be

```
K = pylab.errorbar(...
```

As per [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html?highlight=errorbar#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar), `errorbar()` returns one container object, which contains itself 3 objects (the plot line, the cap lines, and the barlines). You therefore cannot unpack this in a 1-element tuple. Either you store the container in a single variable, or your unpack the content of the container in 3 variable.

This works too:

```
line,caplines,barlines = pylab.errorbar(...
```